# Use "and" in the linq join predicate

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to Use two field in my join predicate in linq.How can i add the other field ?

```
    var Result = from Period in context.PeriodCosts
                 join Name in context.Name on Period.ID equals Name.PeriodID 
                /*"Problem is here ==> */and   
                 Period.CCID equals Name.CCID"
                 select Name;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use anonymous type:

```
var Result = from Period in context.PeriodCosts
             join Name in context.Name
                 on new { ID = Period.ID, CCID = Period.CCID }
                 equals new { ID = Name.PeriodID, CCID = Name.CCID }
             Period.CCID equals Name.CCID"
             select Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
 var Result = from Period in context.PeriodCosts
             join Name in context.Name on 
             new{Period.ID, Period.CCID} equals new { Name.PeriodID, Name.CCID}               
             select Name;
```